# Versioning project libraries with Git (came from vss)

Tags: git, versioning, libraries, visual-sourcesafe

i'm a newbie of git, since now I used vss.
I have converted my project vss repository to a git repository.
now I have some question about versioning my project modules.

Assume this case:

MainProject.exe      v. 1.1.0.0

ProjectLibrary1.dll  v. 1.0.0.1

now with vss I have a batch for versioning who accomplish these steps:

1. Increment version of MainProject.exe from v. 1.1.0.0 to v. 1.1.0.1
2. Add label to MainProject vss folder "v. 1.1.0.1"
3. if ProjectLibrary1.dll has some changed since v. 1.0.0.1 then:

   - increment his version to v. 1.0.0.2
   - add label to ProjectLibrary1 vss folder "v. 1.0.0.2"

With git labels are replaced by tags, and tags are unique for repository, so in the above case i would like to accomplish this steps:

1. Increment version of MainProject.exe from v. 1.1.0.0 to v. 1.1.0.1
2. if ProjectLibrary1.dll has some changes since v. 1.0.0.1 then:

   - increment his version to v. 1.0.0.2
3. Add tag "v. 1.1.0.1"

how to do point 2? 
How to check git for changes committed inside ProjectLibrary1 folder after v. 1.0.0.1?

Thanks

Comment: Why not have two separate repositories, one for your main project and one for your library? Also it's a bad idea to put .exe and .dll files into the repository at all: store the source version control and the outputs elsewhere (backed-up file server or whatever).

Comment: @MatthewStrawbridge inside the repository I have only source code and no binaries, exe and dll are for explain the versioning process. I would like to have a single repository for all the solution libraries, so clone and modify code is related to a single repository.

Comment: Take a look at [submodules](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules).

Comment: If you put both projects in one git repository then you should mark them with one version, because you change them together in terms of git.
If you want to change them separately you should put them in different git repositories and start to use dependency management tool. Think of that as of "single point of change". In this case it's a git repository because it holds your sources.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer not to change version numbers and create git tags automatically.

Instead I use the git describe functionality to get the current tag and changes made after.

For example, I've tagged some version of a library with tag v0.1.0.
If I haven't made changes (and commits), git describe will return v0.1.0. If I have made some changes git describe will return v0.1.0-N-gGITHASH, where N is the number of commits made after the tag was set, and gGITHASH is the hash of a current commit.

Based on this information you can create Windows version number 0.1.0.N. And put a version string with a hash in the 'Informal version' field.
If you continue introduce changes without setting a new tag the N will growth. If you set a new tag (for example, v0.2.0) the N will became zero again.

The git describe can provide you with an information about uncommited changes in your repository.